# Update/append serializer.data in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I update/append `serializer.data` in Django Rest Framework?

data = serializer.data.update({"item": "test"}) not working

`return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`

`serializer.data` is `<class 'rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnDict'>`

Answer (score 66):

Unfortunately, `serializer.data` is a property of the class and therefore **immutable**. Instead of adding items to `serializer.data` you can **copy `serializer.data` to another `dict`**.  You can try this:

```
newdict={'item':"test"}
newdict.update(serializer.data)
return Response(newdict, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

[Read more about `property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property)

Comment: i think this is useful for passing additional data in the `Response` that are not part of the serializer/model (thus not validated)

Comment: this won't solve the case where you want the serialized data to update a model.

Comment: What use case would there be for adding updating a model with extra data? In that situation the serializer is probably best to be modified. I can see this solution being useful for maybe adding some computed data or something else unrelated to the resource in a response.

Comment: @wdfc I think he may be looking for this: serializer=MySerializer(data=request.data,instance=model_instance,partial=True)  serializer.valid()  serializer.save()

Comment: In the case you have multiple serialized objects in your serializer.data, you can use something like this:   newdict={'item':"test"}      
      newdict.update({'result_from_serializer' :serializer.data})

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you might use SerializerMethodField to add additional data by adding a custom method to the serializer.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

You can use such a method to return any data, wether in context of the model or not.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```

Comment: I had to make just one addition and that was to add 'days_since_joined' to my fields= list.  This isn't in the sample code above (or from the DRF documentation), but is required in my implementation.

Answer (score 8):

You don't.

If you need to pass extra data to the serializer's create/update please do so while calling serializer.save() [as explained in the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save)

Answer (score 5):

We can update the data passed in response with `serializer._data`

sample code

```
class SampleAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView)
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        application = serializer.save(status='pending')
        my_response_data = {'id': 110, 'name': 'Batta'}
        serializer._data = out_data
```

`serializer._data` will make the magic.
Reference: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L260

Answer (score 4):

The `serializer.data` object is a instance of ReturnList that is immutable. What you can do to workaround this limitation is transform the `serializer.data` object into a simple Python list(), then append the value you want so you can use your transformed list in Response() method like this:

```
def get(self, request):
    serializer = YourAmazingSerializer(many=True)
    new_serializer_data = list(serializer.data)
    new_serializer_data.append({'dict_key': 'dict_value'})
    return Response(new_serializer_data)
```

Then, your response will have your new obj